# Reverse calculate cases per hundred thousand to find population

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to figure out how to find the actual population of a municipality from the number of coronavirus cases per 100,000. There are 15 cases, and they amount to 9.58 per 100,000 people. How would I go about this in for example Excel?

I am trying to do this as I have three municipalities with different populations, different amount of cases and different amount of cases per 100,000, and I want to in the end find the number of people per 100,000 for the three municipalities combined.

I calculated (9.58/100000) and then 15/the result of the previous calculation. Had no idea if it was correct or not though.

Comment: Dimensional analysis: $$\left[15 ~\text{cases}\right] \times \left[\frac{100,000 ~\text{people}}{9.58 ~\text{cases}}\right].$$

Comment: @user2661923 cool! I calculated (9.58/100000) and then 15/the result of the previous calculation. Had no idea if it was correct or not though. Now that I have the total of all cases per municipality and then also total population, so 547674 people and 48 cases, how do I then convert that to "per 100000"? Also please post this an answer, so that I can mark it as the solution!

Comment: I am not allowed to post this as an answer, since you haven't really shown work, directly in your question.  This is in accordance with [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  I suggest that you use the math explicitly as I laid it out, because you end up with $$\left[\text{cases}\right] \times \left[\frac{\text{people}}{\text{cases}}\right] = \text{people}.$$

Comment: @user2661923, there, added my work to the question. I am not disputing or refusing to use your answer by the way, it's good. I wanted you to post it because I think it is good (so I am going to use it).. I just added a follow up question